# Nano syntax highlighting rules for D

Tags: syntax-highlighting, d, nano

I'm just getting started learning the D language, and I'm curious whether a `.nanorc` file with syntax highlighting rules for D is available. Nothing turns up with a quick google search.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've just made one, for you and me (since I don't believe that anyone else in the world uses nano for D :-)

Have a look: https://github.com/vinesworth/d-nanorc

Answer (score 3):

Mostly incomplete list of tools that support D (feel free to edit, its a wiki)

[IDEs](http://wiki.dlang.org/IDEs)

[Editors](http://wiki.dlang.org/Editors)